# Is the version number appended to the app-store app name?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I added a version number to my app on the first upload.  It is 1.0

Will this number be part of my app name?  That's what apple says on the
documentation.

I don't want it to be part of my app name.  Must it be part of the app name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your app version number (eg, 1.0) is not appended to your app name at any point. The Apple documentation is correct - the version number appears on the appstore as follows:

[image]

2) If you have Administrator rights on your apple developer account, then you can login to ITC (iTunes Connect) at the link below:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

From here, you can go "Manage Your Applications" and then find your app. (add it and follow the steps if it's not done already) Once you have clicked on your app, you will see the following:

[image]

The Apple ID as shown in the image above will be a numerical string.